# Do higher order differences within explicit schemes negatively effect stability?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences

I was reading the paragraph in section E.4 of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2308.05732.pdf) paper, where the authors discuss adding longer histories in neural/numerical PDE solvers and claim that "*using higher-order differences [in time] within an explicit autoregressive scheme is known to deteriorate the rollout stability and introduce exponentially increasing errors over time.*"

What are the reasons for this reduced stability? I can think of one possible reason: as we include higher-order differences, the condition for stability becomes more restrictive, and we require smaller stepsizes in time. Are there any other reasons?

Comment: I think the reason might be just the higher order difference scheme for time derivative leads to numerical instability since the scheme $\frac{\sum_{i} c_i u(t + i\delta t)}{\delta t}$ would have exponentially large sum of the coefficients $\sum_{i} |c_i|$ which will accumulate rounding error faster.

Comment: but this does not explain (at least far from rigor) why their network also would suffer if a longer history is applied. There are multiple possibilities, the paper deliberately avoids explaining in detail, but instead, gives a vague (but could be related) explanation.

Comment: @Yimin Thank you for your answer. The paper shows adding history improves one-step predictions, but worsens long-term stability. This is counterintuitive and makes me think it has something to do with the condition for stability—although a smaller step size seems to exacerbate this issue. What other possibilities do you think might explain this phenomenon?

Comment: For their work, the training process learns to distinguish a random noise from the solution, which can be understood as a filtering effect like FNO. In speaking of Fourier space, if the problem is linear, then there should be still no issue. For nonlinear problem, more history might cover more interaction frequencies, so in short time, the prediction still looks good, while high frequencies had a chance to mix with noises, which accumulates in longer time and leads to less accuracy of prediction. So there is a sweet zone. That is my understanding.

Comment: @Yimin Really nice insights!